# Getting Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined with bootstrap carousel script

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I created a `carousel` with `Bootstrap 3.3` and it works on my local machine, but when I upload the whole thing on server where the bootstrap js file is being compiled together with other files in a single file, I get this error:

`Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined` - has anybody faced this and are there any known solutions to this issue?

Comment: Can you link to the page with the error? Or could you put it in jsFiddle?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

For me it was because I hadn't set an `active` class on any of the slides.

Comment: If you compile bootstrap you can fix it by editing the carousel.js
for the line 
`$next[0].offsetWidth` // force reflow
Change to
    `if (typeof $next == 'object' && $next.length) $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow`

Comment: in my  case affecting both  active class  and also it may also rendred issue  dive load before its contain loaded

Comment: @fourgablesguy Hi, may I know what do you mean exactly by - compile bootstrap? 
how can bootstrap be manually compiled? Do u mean building the whole project?

Comment: @AshishGoyal yes you can build from source the bootstrap js and css and even documentation using node package manager. There are instructions on how to do that in the documentation for bootstrap See Build Tools section of the documentation on how to build bootstrap.

Answer (score 109):

For me, I changed `class='carousel-item'` to `class='item'` like this

```
<div class="item">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="..." alt="...">
</div>
```

Comment: 'carousel-item' is from the v4 alpha example. For this reason, I left it in but added 'item' so it would also work in v3

Comment: Worked for me too. Not sure why.

Comment: Thank you so much! After agonizing over this problem for over an houre, this solved the problem for me too.

Comment: I am using both BootStrap 4 and 3 (long story) so adding item and carousel-item fixed the issue for me (neither one alone worked).

Comment: Using 4 beta 1 that https://pingendo.com is currently using, and had to add item alongside with carousel-item did the trick

Comment: Two years later, using bs4, using both item and carousel-item works for me too. By now perhaps the error is built in?

Answer (score 8):

Remove the class 'Carousal slide' on page load & add it dynamically when image gets loaded using jquery.This fixed for me

Comment: I am creating the whole carousel html content in jquery dynamically and still get the same error

Comment: Note that we need to initialize the carousel using .carousel() method.

Answer (score 1):

I got same error. Because i used v4 alpha class names like `carousel-control-next` When i changed with v3, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error, but in my case I wrote class names for carousel item as  .carousel-item the bootstrap.css is referring .item.
SO ERROR solved.
carosel-item is renamed to item

```
<div class="carousel-item active"></div>
```

RENAMED To the following:

```
<div class="item active"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Change to if (typeof $next == 'object' && $next.length) $next[0].offsetWidth" -did not help. 
if you convert Bootstrap 3 to php(for WordPress theme), when adding WP_Query ($loop = new WP_Query( $args );) insert $count = 0;. And and at the end before endwhile; add $count++;.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the compiled bootstrap, one of the ways of fixing it is by editing the bootstrap.min.js before the line

```
$next[0].offsetWidth
```

force reflow Change to

```
if (typeof $next == 'object' && $next.length) $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced with that problem when I created a dynamic modal popup. And I found a solution that is default we need one blank active item on slide - item set active with nothing.

```html
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active"></div>
  //some slides items was addêd dynamic from database.....
</div>
```

I hope this solution help you