# Bootstrap.js not recognizing offsetWidth when reloading image src with Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just getting starting with Angular, so everything is still a bit new to me.

What's happening right now is that this works in the sense that my HTML gets changed when I switch categories on my gallery navigation. However, once the HTML gets changed, I get this error from Bootstrap:

[Cannot read property of 'offsetWidth' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H9t6.png)

I have a suspicion that this is because in the split second its rebinding the new data, there's nothing there isn't a width for Bootstrap to build the carousel hence the error. Unfortunately I don't have any ideas for how to get around this...

---

Currently this is how I have my code set up, any help would be appreciated!:

index.html

```
 <div class="container page" ng-controller="GalleryNavigation as nav">
    <!--Gallery Navigation: changes what image sources to load on click-->
    <div id="gallery-nav">
        <ul class="col-md-1">
            <li ng-class="{active:nav.isSelected(1)}">
                <a href ng-click="nav.selectSection(1)">01. print</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:nav.isSelected(2)}">
                <a href ng-click="nav.selectSection(2)">02. web</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:nav.isSelected(3)}">
                <a href ng-click="nav.selectSection(3)">03. video</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="gallery-wrapper">
            <!--All artwork loaded when clicked; refer to app.js for work directive-->
            <work></work>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

print.html (sorry for the poor indentation :( )

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <!--filter by library type selected in the gallery navigation bar-->
        <div class="item real" ng-repeat="slide in nav.slides | filter:nav.currLibrary">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" alt="..." class="image">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                {{slide.title}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

app.js

```
//Controller for Gallery Navigation    
app.controller('GalleryNavigation',function(){
    this.section="1";
    this.slides=Library;
    this.currLibrary="print";
    this.selectSection=function(setSec){
        this.section=setSec;
        if(setSec==1){
            this.currLibrary="print";
        }
        if(setSec==2){
            this.currLibrary="web";
        }
        console.log(this.slides);
    };
    this.isSelected=function(checkSec){
        return this.section==checkSec;
    };});
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027830/getting-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-undefined-with-bootstrap-carousel) question.

Comment: @Goldenowner That was it, thank you so much!