# bootstrap carousel not working in mvc application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-carousel

I am getting the error is JavaScript run time error: Unable to get property 'offsetWidth' of undefined or null reference.

```
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
          <script>
           $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "@(Url.Action("GetHomeImageurls", "BannerImage"))",
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                //debugger;
                var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
                var table = jsonData.Table;
                var str = '';
                var str1 = '';
                var text = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
                    if (i == 0)
                        text = 'active';
                    else
                        text = '';
                    str = str + '<div class="item ' + text + '"><img src="' + table[i].ImagePath + '" alt="image" style="height:400px;width:800px;"/></div>';
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
                    if (i == 0)
                        text = 'active';
                    else
                        text = '';
                    str1 = str1 + '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="'+i+'" class="'+text+'"></li>';
                }
                $('.carousel-inner').html(str);
                $('.carousel-indicators').html(str1);


            },
            error: function (data) {
                debugger;

            }
        });
   </script>
```

Here i am using bootstarp.js and jquery.js,I am unable to find where is offsetWidth is used.Please find where the exception occurs in above code.

Comment: What is your `GetHomeImageurls()` code.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027830/getting-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-undefined-with-bootstrap-carousel/29580816

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you try to reference on the `offsetWidth` member of a variable, but the variable is `undefined` or `null`. Since it is `undefined` or `null`, it does not have an `offsetWidth` member, hence the error. You will need to find the exact place of this error and check for the variable to be truey, like

```
if (myVariable && (typeof myVariable.offsetWidth !== "undefined")) {
    //Do something with myVariable.offsetWidth
}
```

Comment: I am not using offsetWidth any where.@Lajos

Comment: @Jaganath your error message says otherwise. Check the error in the browser console, go to the line of the error and see where you used offsetWidth. There is a chance that you have not written such a code, but use an already written script which uses it.