# Dynamic Bootstrap carousal not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a dynamic bootstrap carousel, which shows images from the database.

Everything works fine but sometimes the carousel won't move left or right, even after clicking the arrow button. But when I refresh the page it works fine,

**My code is as follows**.

```
function show_gallary(id){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>home/fetch_gallary_modal/"+id,// url to your upload process file
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        contentType: false,
        cache: true,
        processData:false,// tell jQuery not to set contentType
        success: function(data){
            $(".events").empty();  
            var img = data[0].image.split(",");
            $("#show_gallary").modal('show');
            $("#gal_modal_description").html(data[0].description);
            $("#gal_modal_header").html(data[0].name);
            var cnt=img.length;
            var k=1;
            for(var i=0;i<cnt;i++){
                var url="<?php echo base_url()?>gallery/"+img[i];
                if(i==0){
                    $(".events").append('<div class="item active"><img style="width:50%;" id="gl'+k+'" src="'+url+'"></div>');
                }
                else{
                    $(".events").append('<div class="item"><img style="width:50%;" id="gl'+k+'" src="'+url+'"></div>');
                }
                k++;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Carousal div**

```
<div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner events"></div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

when I open the console it shows an error that

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined

I have used the "active" class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined with bootstrap carousel script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027830/getting-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-undefined-with-bootstrap-carousel)

Comment: but its not the fix. I have used the .active class