# Getting Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined with Bootstrap carousel error message

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I'm getting the following error message: Getting Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined with Bootstrap carousel error message with my Bootstrap carousel.

Here is my code:

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" >
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php foreach ($repairPics as $ind => $pics) {  ?>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $ind;?>" <?php echo (($ind == 0) ? 'class="active"' : '');?>"></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="margin-left: 10%;height: 100%;">
        <?php foreach ($repairPics as $ind => $pics) {  ?>
            <div class="carousel-item <?php echo (($ind == 0) ? 'active' : '');?>">
            <img style="height: 100%;" class="d-inline-block w-100" src="https://earthsky.org/upl/2017/06/Interplanetary-Transport-System-SpaceX-Elon-Musk-300x158.jpg" alt="Starship">
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
     </div>
    <a class="carousel-nav-controls carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-nav-controls carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" style="right: 0%;">
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my js code:

```
  $("#myCarousel").carousel();

  $(".carousel-item").click(function(){
        $("#myCarousel").carousel(0);
  });

  $("a.carousel-nav-controls.carousel-control-prev").click(function(){
        $("#myCarousel").carousel("prev");
  });

  $("a.carousel-nav-controls.carousel-control-next").click(function(){
                $("#myCarousel").carousel("next");
   });
```

What could be causing the error?

Ty,
Kevin

Comment: Try moving the `</div>` that is under `</ul>` to the very bottom so that the carousel div actually wraps the carousel items.

Comment: That was a formatting issue on my part. I changed it.

Comment: Your example works properly for me. Have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7goa6r8/6/). Seems like another issue in your example that is not displayed, yet.

Comment: The problem should be that your `"active"` class is not set for any reason. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29580816/3623608).

Comment: The problem is that I did. If you look at the following code: <div class="carousel-item <?php echo (($ind == 0) ? 'active' : '');?>" style="height: 100%;">, I already did set the image to active if the index is 0

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

The problem was not within the Javascript, nor active settings. It had to do with the carousel-item class. I changed it from carousel-item to item. It is now working. Looks like I might have to upgrade Bootstrap.